# How to add a custom action with parameters in InstallShield Limited Edition?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installshield-le

I used to add custom action in setup project and set parameter on install and another parameter on uninstall.

I want to pass `/i` as parameter to an executable file on install action and `/u` on uninstall action.

How to do this using InstallShield limited edition?

Comment: If you need to create anything more than a simple "copy everything to program files" installer that you probably shouldn't try to use the LE version for it. As the name says, it's quite limited.

Comment: So not all supported features in the old installer are support in InstallShield LE?